# dojo - object scope for methods in widgets using lang.hitch()

Tags: javascript, scope, dojo, widget, dom-events

I have a dojo customized widget template as shown below

```
<div>
   <div class = "btn" data-dojo-attach-point = "buttonDiv"></div>
   <a href="#" data-dojo-attach-point ="aDiv">"Click me!!"</a>
</div>
```

In my js class in `postCreate()`, I am attaching a click event to the hyperlink

```
//inside postCreate function
postCreate: function() {
     this.inherited(arguments);
     var me = this;
     me.own(on(me.aDiv,"click",lang.hitch(me,me.onClickFun)));
},
onClickFun: function (evt,me) {
      // here this is not the widget object but, the hyperlink node.
}
```

As per the above code sample, inside onClickFun, "this" object is pointing to the a tag, created in template. Is there a way, that I can get an handle to the widget object? What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The example you've provided works for me, though it can be cleaned up a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/okgdntxh/

Comment: @KenFranqueiro: Thanks! After looking at fiddle, I know what it was that I was doing wrong. Instead of calling the onclick callback as me.onClickFun I needed to call it as 'onClickFun'. Although I am not sure how 'onClickFun' got referenced here ?

Comment: Either one should work, actually - both bind execution context, but referencing it as a string performs late binding (where it essentially looks up `me['onClickFun']` at the time the function is called).